# SKSpriteNode Texture Black Box

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

For some reason when I use certain SKSpriteNode textures, they appear as black boxes in the app. For example in my game scene in Xcode I see:
[image: Before]

But in the actual app I see:

[image: After]

Does anyone know why this happens, or how to fix it? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Even though the picture size after manually changing the size was fine, the original picture size was too big. I fixed the issue by simply resizing the original image.

Comment: Not working for me. My image is a lot smaller than the sprite node and still you just get a black box.